# values from Form not parse over to controller in MVC framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

**Task**

Am suppose to parse values that I have entered in the respective form field into the controller- action.php. And have the values reflected in the error log that is in action.php, this is to ensure that the `method =POST` is posting the correct value from the view to the controller.

**Issue**
I was initially able to parse values over, and it was reflected in my error_log. However, for unknown reason, values parsed over now are of the wrong value. It means that if I were to select "Others" and input in my fields, the parse values reflected in the error log is showing details of Agency 3, or if I were ot select "Agency 1", rightfully, values of agency 1 should be post over in the error_log but the values posted are values from agency 3.

I am perplexed as I have tried other field values and it was able to parse over correctly.

Can anyone please help me

**code**

Form field in View:

```
<form name="form_Agent" id="form_Agent" method="POST" action="action.php" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)">

<li class="bigfield">

                    <select name ="AgencyDetails" id="AgencyDetails" onchange = "return val(this.value);">
                    <option value ="0" selected = "selected"> ..</option>
                    ....
                    </select>
            </li>

<!--: when user select "Others"-->
            <div id = "extradiv" style ="display:none">

                ...
             </div>

             <!--: when user select other options other than "Others"-->
            <div  id = "Agency1" style ="display:none">
           ....</div>

</form>
<!--: Set Conditional check, if user clicks Others, direct to additional input field: Agent Name, Agency Registration Number, Agency Address if click Agency 1 or 2 or 3, to display value-->
<script>
function val(x) {
.....
}

</script>
```

Error log in Controller: action.php:

```
error_log(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."_-mobile,agencyName: ".$_POST['agencyName']."\n",3,"/var/tmp/value/value.log");
error_log(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."_-mobile, agencyRegistrationNum: ".$_POST['agentRegistrationNum']."\n",3,"/var/tmp/value/value.log");
```

error log result

```
2015-09-08 _-mobile: 
2015-09-08 _-mobile:
```

Comment: I think problem is you are passing 3 values with the same names did you tried to pass only one value??

Comment: its not mean then hidden value will not pass to server :)

Comment: @MuhammadUsman give me a moment, I am testing it out individually. Will update you on the outcome

Comment: @MuhammadUsman and what do you mean by hidden value will not pass to server?

Comment: means other values will also pass to the server :) dont get me wrong :)

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I have tested it out individually and it works. However, this is what I have discovered: for e.g: if I were to just test "Others", it works beautifully. However, if i were to add in other elements such as "Agency 1" and "Others", the issue is there, whereby it will display  details of "Agency 1" when I click "Others" and input other values. How is is this so?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Could you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a simple syntax error that I have overlooked, the 'name' & 'id' are the same for each extra div. Hence, html tends to look at the latest tag inputs. What I did to solve the following issue is to assign different  'name' and 'id' to each div. Hence it goes like that:

```
<div id = "extradiv" style ="display:none">

            <li class="bigfield"><input placeholder="Agency Name" type="text" name="agencyOthersName" id="agencyOthersName"/></li>
        <li class="bigfield"><input placeholder="Agency Registration Num" type="text" name="agentOthersRegistrationNum" id="agentOthersRegistrationNum"/></li>
        <li class="bigfield"><input placeholder="Agency Address" type="text" name="agentOthersAddress" id="agentOthersAddress"/></li>

         </div>

         <!--: when user select other options other than "Others"-->
        <div  id = "Agency1" style ="display:none">
       <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Name 1" type="text" name="agency1Name" id="agency1Name"/></li>
        <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Registration Num 1" type="text" name="agent1RegistrationNum" id="agent1RegistrationNum"/></li>
        <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Address 1" type="text" name="agent1Address" id="agent1Address"/></li>

         </div>

         <div  id = "Agency2" style ="display:none" >
       <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Name 2" type="text" name="agency2Name" id="agency2Name"/></li>
        <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Registration Num 2" type="text" name="agent2RegistrationNum" id="agent2RegistrationNum"/></li>
        <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Address 2" type="text" name="agent2Address" id="agent2Address"/></li></div>
```